# Branches names no longer appearing in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-branch

I've updated VSCode to the latest version - Feb 2023 and the branches' names no longer appear above the commits, as shown in the image below.

How can I make the branches appear again?

[image: VS Code Git History]

Comment: How do you get to this screen?

Comment: @TimothyG. you get this screen from installing Visual Studio Git History extension.

Looking at the extension's GitHub's page, it appears to be a known issue.

https://github.com/DonJayamanne/gitHistoryVSCode/issues/730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This as been resoved by the VS Code extension author.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).